# Hotels/cottages with private hot tub access in Colorado Springs/Denver, Colorado

Tags: hotels, denver

One of the experiences that I would like to add to me wish list is to be in a hot-tub while outside when its really snowing hard. Are there any hotels/ cottages with private access to a hot-tub outside of your room in the CS/Denver area? Preference goes to hotels, but cottages are OK too.

Comment: Does it have to be a hot tub only for yourself, or is a shared one OK? (The latter are a lot more common than the former, which tends to only be expensive rooms in expensive places that offer it)

Comment: Prefer private, not a community one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out [AirBnb](http://airbnb.com) has a list of amenities, including pools spas and hot tubs, which can be used to filter out properties. I would use this as a starting point for your search. [Here](https://airbnb.com/listings/177833?s=23) is a random property mentioning a hot tub in Colorado Springs.

In my opinion you will find more hot tubs in private properties in Colorado Springs. Denver will probably offer more communal saunas and pools.